# Related to context in Android

Tags: java, android

I do not understand context very well yet. In most of the cases, I see people using 'this' keyword for context in the constructor. I am writing an application which has two activities - MainActivity and DisplayMessageActivity. Both activities contain menu items - Search and Settings. If I touch 'Search', a toast should appear saying - "Search was clicked" and same for the settings. Since these actions will be same for touches from both activities, I made a separate class MenuMethods which will handle the toast display. MenuMethods will contain 2 public static void methods to display the toast. Here is the relevant code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        MenuMethods.openSearch();
    }
    if (id==R.id.action_search){

        MenuMethods.openSettings();
    }
```

and the methods in MenuMethods class goes like this:

```
public class MenuMethods {
public static void openSearch(){

    Toast.makeText(this, "Search was Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static void openSettings(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Settings was Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Possible error : (application).MenuMethods.this cannot be referenced from a static context.
How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MenuMethods.openSearch(MyActivity.this);

public static void openSearch(Context ctx){

    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Search was Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

There's little reason though to have a separate class `MenuMethods` in your case

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. I am just a beginner. I am still learning. I was writing this code to understand context. In this case I think MenuMethods.this is not a valid context because it's not extending any activity. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, MenuMethods is just a class you wrote, it does not know anything about Context. On the contrary, Activity extends Context therefore an Activity is a Context. Context is a class, nothing else